# Is it possible to configure a .htaccess file to access example.com/subdomain/ without any redirects?

Tags: domains, htaccess, subdomain, subdirectory

I need to configure 2 CMS's on a domain. The first is on `example.com`. The other is on `subdomain.example.com`. Is it possible to configure a *.htaccess* file so that the second CMS is accessible as `example.com/subdomain/` without redirects?

Comment: What are the two CMS's  My hunch is to tell you no, because CMS1 is domain.com.  Adding CMS2 as a subfolder breaks the operation of CMS1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) can be configured from *.htaccess* to serve content from a different server or host as a subfolder.   You would use a rewrite rule with the `[P]` flag (for proxy) in your *.htaccess* to do so:

```
RewriteRule ^/subdomain/(.*) http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse  /subdomain/ http://subdomain.example.com/
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. After your answer I found a detailed explanations of these instructions with examples [here](http://www.askapache.com/hosting/reverse-proxy-apache.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not without redirects.  The only way you can do it without a redirect is to use a reverse proxy (either apache, or nginx would work great).